# Probability of two darts getting a score of 10 on regular hexagon dart board

Tags: probability

The question I'm working on is shown below:

[image]

I've reasoned that the probability of throwing a dart for each section are: $Pr(1)=\frac{1}{6}$, $Pr(2)=\frac{1}{12}$, $Pr(3)=\frac{1}{3}$, $Pr(4)=\frac{1}{4}$, $Pr(5)=\frac{1}{8}$ and $Pr(6)=\frac{1}{24}$. I'm stuck how to proceed from here.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far other than finding the probabilities of landing in each area?

Comment: @Ziauddin Ahmed Mohammed: To get a score of $10$ with $2$ darts, what are the possible ordered pairs of scores (first dart, second dart)?

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Answer (score 3):

$P(3)=\dfrac{1}{3}$
$\rightarrow P(1)=\dfrac{1}{6} \rightarrow P(2)=\dfrac{1}{12}\rightarrow P(4)=\dfrac{1}{6}+P(2)=\dfrac{1}{4}$

$P(5)+P(6)=\dfrac{1}{6}$
but $P(6)=\dfrac{1}{3}P(5)\rightarrow \dfrac{1}{3}P(5)+P(5)=\dfrac{1}{6}\rightarrow P(5)=\dfrac{1}{8}\,and\, P(6)=\dfrac{1}{24}$
$P(1)+P(2)+P(3)+P(4)+P(5)+P(6)=\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{1}{12}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{8}+\dfrac{1}{24}=1$

$\begin{align}P(X_1+X_2=10)&=P(X_1=4,X_2=6)+P(X_1=5,X_2=5)+P(X_1=6,X_2=4)\\
&=P(X_1=4)P(X_2=6)+P(X_1=5)P(X_2=5)+P(X_1=6)P(X_2=4)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1}{24}+\dfrac{1}{8}\cdot\dfrac{1}{8}+\dfrac{1}{24}\cdot\dfrac{1}{4}\\
&=\dfrac{7}{192}\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

You found the probabilities of hitting the sections correctly.

Hint:

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]